# Terminal runs commands on startup and I cannot find where they are coming from

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, docker

I have accidentally put `winehq.key` into `/etc/bash_completion.d/` in the process of `docker-machine` completion installation.

I've tried to set up docker-machine auto completion and followed these instructions from the official website: https://docs.docker.com/machine/completion/

I've copied this to my terminal:

```
sudo curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/machine/v0.16.0/contrib/completion/bash/docker-machine.bash -o /etc/bash_completion.d/docker-machine
```

Now every time I open a new terminal, it tries to run something that looks like the following:

```
-----BEGIN: command not found
mQGNBFwOmrgBDAC9FZW3dFpew1hwDaqRfdQQ1ABcmOYu1NKZHwYjd+bGvcR2LRGe: command not found
bash: R5dfRqG1Uc/5r6CPCMvnWxFprymkqKEADn8eFn+aCnPx03HrhA+lNEbciPfTHylt: No such file or directory
bash: 6jCdl6eoCCkKNOIbr/MMSkd2KqAqDVM5cnnlQ7q+AXzwNpj3RGJVoBxbS0nn9JWY: No such file or directory
QNQrWh9rAcMIGT+b1le0: command not found
=4lsa: command not found
-----END: command not found
```

I did not copy everything just a few lines.

I removed the file I copied using `curl`, but it did not work. It seems that there is nothing new in `~/.bashrc` as well. How to prevent terminal from running this on startup?

Comment: It appears to try to execute a GnuPG/PGP key or message. Have you also looked in `~/.bash_profile` and/or `~/.profile`? Do you have calls to `gpg` in any of these files?

Comment: I don't have `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.profile` was last modified a year ago

Comment: welcome, Check the filenames under `/etc/bash_completion.d/` directory  and its contents. You have added the gpg key of winhq somewhere.

Comment: thanks. It was `winehq.key` in bash_completion.d directory. You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the filenames under `/etc/bash_completion.d/` directory and its contents. You have added the gpg key of [winehq](https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/) somewhere.